# How can I get and post inside one route?

Tags: javascript, express

Here is my route:

```
 app.all("/checkoutupdateprods", async (res,req, next) =>{
  
  const url = GRAPHQL_CUSTOM_URL;
  console.log("in b_server.js", res.body);
  
  let data = res;

  await fetch(url, checkOut_ProductsInStock(data.body))
    .then(res => console.log(res.json()))
    .catch(err => req.send(err));
});
```

Starting from the client or front end, I pass a json string to the back end/server. I then create a graphql query with the json string which holds ids I need. I use the graphql query and url to send a get request to shopify to retrieve the products with those ids.

So that is why I am using app.all() so I can do post and get inside one route. My problem now is the res or response is set to the post json string from the client not the response I get from shopify for the products I need.

I am not sure what to do about this. Anyone have a suggestion?

EDIT**---
I am using this now, but am getting a promise pending and I do not know why.

```
app.post("/checkoutupdateprods", async (req,res, next) =>{
  
  const url = GRAPHQL_CUSTOM_URL;
  console.log(req.body);
  
  let data = req;
  
  await fetch(url, checkOut_ProductsInStock(data.body))
    .then(res => console.log(res.json()))
    .catch(err => res.send(err));
});
```

Comment: First off, it's unlikely this use of `app.all()` is correct.  You're providing the exact same response no matter what type of incoming request it is.  I can't think of any case where that's correct design.  Second, your `req` and `res` function arguments are declared and/or named backwards.  `req` should be first and then you have to fix your use of those too.

Comment: Then, you need to send a response back to the original request.  You can use the data from your `fetch()` to create that response if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting promise pending because you are redeclaring the `res` variable in the fetch promise chain.

```
app.post("/checkoutupdateprods", async (req, res, next) =>{

const url = GRAPHQL_CUSTOM_URL;
  console.log(req.body);
  
  let data = req;
  
  await fetch(url, checkOut_ProductsInStock(data.body))
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(resData => {
        console.log(resData);
        res.json(resData);
    })
    .catch(err => res.send(err));
});
```